# Couchbase EC2 Community AMI and hostname

Tags: amazon-ec2, couchbase, ec2-ami

I've been looking for some good documentation on the ec2 AMI's for community couchbase and updating couchbase to run with hostnames. What I did find in the couchbase docs are actually out of date as seen [here](http://docs.couchbase.com/couchbase-manual-1.8/#using-couchbase-in-the-cloud)

What I actually have is `-name 'babysitter_of_ns_1@127.0.0.1' \` and `-run ns_babysitter_bootstrap -- \` The addition of babysitter_of_ns without any documentation makes me wonder if this is actually where I make the change.

Has anyone successfully changed the AMI config to run with a hostname? Would like to somehow automate this as much as possible so if the internal ip changes it doesn't create an issue of the node being unreachable.

It would be great if couchbase had more documentation around this.

Answer (score 1):

Try the [2.2 version of the Manual](http://docs.couchbase.com/couchbase-manual-2.2/#couchbase-bestpractice-cloud) - there's a selector at the top right of the page. That discusses how to achieve what you want on 2.2 (or whichever version you are using).

Comment: I had read that. It may be helpful in some cases. But I'm looking how to configure it even with one dev server. In that case would need to shutdown and edit the script as in 2.0.1 so any REST seems like it would not work. Really looking for more documentation for the AMI than has been provided by couchbase.